# "car" package url out of date

Tags: r, package, r-mosaic

I am trying to follow along in the Statistical Sleuth [here](http://www3.amherst.edu/~nhorton/sleuth/) to teach myself some regression analysis for my job in machine learning, but when installing the "mosaic" package it requires the "car" package. So I did `install.packages(car)` but I see that the url R is trying to open is

http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/**car_2.0-20.zip**

However, the correct url (as seen [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html)) is

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/**car_2.0-21.zip**

How can I make R open a custom url and install this package?

Comment: If the url is wrong, email the author! he is the only one who can do something with it

Comment: To install the package from within R, type:  install.packages("car", dep=TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at `update.packages()`, and there's an update for the `car` package.

```
> update.packages()
#  ...
# car :
#  Version 2.0-20 installed in /home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1 
#  Version 2.0-21 available at http://cran.rstudio.com
Update (y/N/c)?
```

Entering `y`, the `URL` in question appears in the download message

```
Update (y/N/c)?  y
# trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/car_2.0-21.tar.gz'
# Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 584149 bytes (570 Kb)
# opened URL
# ==================================================
# downloaded 570 Kb
```

So I would probably install `car` first, then try `mosaic`